# Elasticsearch "must" query isn't mapping of index

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I don't make query in elasticsearch for .net core with must operator. I use .net 5, Elasticsearch 7.16.0, NEST 7.16.0.

```
BeginDate = BeginDate == null ? DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900") : BeginDate;
        EndDate = EndDate == null ? DateTime.Now : EndDate;
        var response = _client.Search<LogModel>(s => s
       .From(page)
       .Size(rowCount)
       .Sort(ss => ss.Descending(p => p.PostDate))
       .Query(q => q
           .Bool(b => b
               .Must(
                   q => q.Term(t => t.LogType, "INFO"),
                   q => q.Term(t => t.RegionCode, RegionCode),
                   q => q.DateRange(dr => dr
                   .Field(p => p.PostDate)
                   .GreaterThanOrEquals(DateMath.Anchored(((DateTime)BeginDate).AddDays(-1)))
                   .LessThanOrEquals(DateMath.Anchored(((DateTime)EndDate).AddDays(1)))
                   ))
                )
             )
       .Index(indexName)
       );
        return response.Documents;
```

Comment: Your query uses `MustNot` but you mention "must"?

Comment: Thank you for warning. I fixed.

Comment: Ok, now can you explain what "doesn't work" means? Can you show a document that should match but doesn't? Usually, depending on your field mappings, using a `Match` query instead of a `Term` one does the trick.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means that the data in elastic is not available in the query. I chose this method because I will query on more than one term. When I tried with Match, I gave up because I got an error when the search parameter was empty.

Comment: I reiterate, can you show a document that should match but doesn't as well as the query parameters that you're using?

Comment: : I sending RegionCode and LogType but result isn't response( [link](https://ibb.co/R4JSSY9) 'Image 1',[link](https://ibb.co/7JPcht4) 'Image 2',[link](https://ibb.co/V9rNQcJ) 'Image 3',[link](https://ibb.co/hsVdcr9) 'Image 4' ).

Comment: Can you update your question with the mapping of your index?

Comment: Ok, I updated. do you know to fix my problem or how to can I search in google?

Comment: I don't see your index mapping

Comment: I think this is the part where I'm mapping. Sorry, I'm new to elasticsearc.  -> [link](https://ibb.co/DzMs9bb)

Comment: What you shared is the query. To get the mapping just run `GET indexName/_mapping` in Kibana Dev Tools

Comment: Oke, I run the query. Response -> https://textdoc.co/7osOBbdMhZ8UWv9y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `Term` queries, you actually need to run them on the `keyword` sub-field, like this:

```
...
q => q.Term(t => t.LogType.Suffix("keyword"), "INFO"),
q => q.Term(t => t.RegionCode.Suffix("keyword"), RegionCode),
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Val :) Your code is run :)